# Rank for a my name and surname when it's not in the content?

Tags: seo, google-search, blog, local-seo, website-features

I have a website which has the post of the results of some research I do on a monthly basis. It is basically survey results.

My name does not appear in my site, and I want my website appear in Google search, when people type my name. Can I do that, and if yes, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things you can do:

1. Use schema markups in your site
2. Add your name in your site (can be in about section)
3. You must have social media profiles; mention your website there and you can also add your social links on your site.
4. Use some backlinks.

Comment: +1 for adding your name to your site.   Google isn't likely to rank a page for a search term when the page doesn't mention that term.

Answer (score 1):

Is your name not allowed anywhere on the site, even if not shown in the primary content?  Have you looked at schema?  Schema gives search engines information about the type and authorship of your content.

https://schema.org/Person

`The publishingPrinciples property indicates (typically via URL) a document describing the editorial principles of an Organization (or individual e.g. a Person writing a blog) that relate to their activities as a publisher, ... pplied to a CreativeWork (e.g. NewsArticle) the principles are those of the party primarily responsible for the creation of the CreativeWork.`

and https://schema.org/CreativeWork

`The author of this content or rating. Please note that author is special in that HTML 5 provides a special mechanism for indicating authorship via the rel tag. That is equivalent to this and may be used interchangeably.`

Comment: Schema is supposed to mark up content on the page.  It shouldn't be used to inject keywords into the page.